# Titlesec: remove space after empty margin section

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

I'm using `titlesec` to assign some custom formatting to my sections. In particular I want to use margin `\section`'s, so that the title section is typeset on the left margin, and the text of that section starts at the same height as the tile.

But I'm having a little problem with the spacing: when a `\section` is immediately followed by a `\subsection`, an unwanted vertical space is added and the title of the subsection does not align anymore with the title of the section (see code and picture bellow). How could I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]{\raggedright\scshape}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{2.5cm}{*2.5}{0.5cm}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*2}{*1}
\begin{document}
\section{First}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second}
\subsection{This is not nice}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{This is fine}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: titlesec spacing bug]

**Update:** As I really need an answer to this (I'm using it in some document that I should deliver soon), I'll offer a bounty to anybody who can bring me an answer.

For whoever decides to tackle this issue, I've navigated a bit into the source from titlesec and found some hackish way to get the desired result. It involves suppressing some `\leavevmode`, delaying an assignment to some spacing parameter *after* the subsection is typeset, and making titlesec to typeset the problematic `\subsection` header directly into the document and not in a “box” for positioning. This regrettably, 
also causes problems with the indentation of the following paragraph.

I would *love* to see a solution simpler than this. Conceptually what I want to do is very simple: after the `\section` somehow tell titlesec to suppress any vertical spacing that would be inserted before the next `\subsection`. So I still hope that some simple solution exists but I'm missing it because I have not much experience on spacing, vertical/horizontal modes and how paragraphs are typeset.

Even if the solution *has* to be more complicated, the ideal would work well together with titlesec and do not break any of its other options. However, in the end I would also settle for a lesser solution which patches the definition of `\subsection` and makes it work at least in my example and my intended configuration given above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very interesting layout. Try the following code. A boolean is hooked to the `\everypar`. This means that if there is plain paragraph first it is set to false and the next subsection will have normal spacing. Note also the strange place where the `\secskip` command end up, but it seems to work.

EDIT 1: Restore original `\everypar` and remove vertical space of `\lastskip` before moving subsection up. Remove all glue and add `\raggedbottom` to prevent stretching.

EDIT 2: It looks if the additional vertical spacing is `\baselineskip`

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifaftersec\aftersecfalse

\newcommand\setsubskip{%
    \global\aftersectrue
    \everypar{%
        \global\aftersecfalse
        \if@noskipsec
            \global\@noskipsecfalse
            \clubpenalty\@M
            \hskip-\parindent
            \begingroup
                \@svsechd\unskip{\hspace{\@tempskipb}}%
            \endgroup
        \else
            \clubpenalty\@clubpenalty\everypar{}%
        \fi}}

\newcommand\subskip{%
  \ifaftersec
     \removelastskip%         EDIT 2
     \vspace{-\baselineskip}% EDIT 2 ??????????????
  \fi
  \global\aftersecfalse}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]{\raggedright\scshape}{}{0pt}{}[\setsubskip]
\titlespacing*{\section}{2.5cm}{2.5ex}{0.5cm}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\subskip\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[]
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{2ex}{1ex}

\raggedbottom
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is looking very good! The small problem I have is that apparently other factors (such as the selected font and font size) also alter the size of the spacing and one has to guesstimate the value to put on the `\vspace`. I've got to go now but, if needed, I can post later a small example showing this problem.

Comment: @Juan A. Navarro: I have changed it a little bit but the `\vspace` value still needs to be measured. Can not figure out where it is added.

Comment: @Juan A. Navarro: It looks if the additional spacing is `\baselineskip`

Comment: Excellent! Works perfectly. I also had to add a `\vspace{-\parskip}` because I'm also using the `parskip` package; but other than that it works great with my settings. It would still be nice to have a version that works with stretchable spaces between pars and sections; but for the moment this is just what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, I can't award you the bounty just yet. But I'll do it as soon as the system allows me to do it.